# IE 11 with Selenium WebDriver: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I don't know why, if I set break point (see in code), its work(it doing click) but if I just run i have an  exception org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException on line (JavascriptExecutor)....
Maybe someone now how to help me or maybe someone knew how to ignore certificate in IE.
Thank you.

```
public class ie {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "drivers/iexploredriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        //caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps); // there i setting break point
        driver.get("https://sasdka.test/uk/");
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Open Internet Options and switch to "Security" Tab
> Select the "Internet" Zone and Unselect the Checkbox "Enable Protected Mode".
> Apply this and do this for remaining 3 zones: 
>  "Local intranet", "Trusted sites" and "Restricted sites".
>
> After this, close the Internet Options and Restart Internet Explorer to get these changes reflected.
> ```